# Access IApplicationEnvironment.ApplicationBasePath

Tags: asp.net-core

How can I access the ASP.NET Core application base path from the property `IApplicationEnvironment.ApplicationBasePath` from anywhere in the code? I'm not in the Startup class but in some other helper class and I need to find the current application's directory from there. There's also no HttpContext because the method will be called independently from requests by a timer. Can I ask the dependency container or something for that information? Is there another way to get this information?

Answer (score 13):

Always check the [announcements on GitHub](https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements) for the beta/rc releases.

As announced [here](https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/issues/171), the `IApplicationEnvrionment` interface has been removed from ASP.NET Core RC2.

To get the path in the Startup method, do this

```
public Startup(IHostingEnvironment hostingEnvironment)
{
    var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
        .SetBasePath(hostingEnvironment.ContentRootPath)
    ...
}
```

If you need it outside, you can either use the static `PlatformServices.Default` method to access it's concrete types or register it with the IoC container and resolve it elsewhere. Later one is preferable for most usages.

Comment: Thanks for the RC2 update. I came from Google and they're full of old junk. Do you mean `PlatformServices.Default.Application.ApplicationBasePath`? I can't see anything similar to `IHostingEnvironment.ContentRootPath` in there.

Comment: No, that points to the dll file. I need the path where the other files are located. I'm deploying a script file with my application and need to get its path at runtime to call an external process with it.

Comment: The problem with using `IHostingEnvironment` is that it forces me to reference the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc` package. I was previously using `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory` in a class library that has nothing to do with MVC. I don't want to reference MVC packages and introduce that unnecessary dependency.

Answer (score 13):

Alternatively, use

`AppContext.BaseDirectory`

Comment: Seems this should be used in favour of the deprecated `PlatformServices.Default.Application.ApplicationBasePath`. It returns the same value for me, .NET Core 2.0.

Comment: I've searched this the whole Stack Overflow for my issue!

Comment: This is actually the one answer which is the equivalent of the previous PlatformServices.Default.Application.ApplicationBasePath value, returning the compiled DLL path and not the root of project when running in debug.

Answer (score 8):

you can now get that from

```
IHostingEnvironment.ContentRootPath
```

IApplicationEnvironment no longer exists